# Need to connect a UISlider created with Interface Builder to non-event code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I have a ViewController that populates a couple of sliders as so:

```
// ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *aSlider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *anotherSlider;

@end

// ViewController.m
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)resetSliders  
{
    NSLog(@"Resetting sliders sl1: %@ sl2: %@", self.aSlider, self.anotherSlider);
    [self.aSlider       setValue:0.5f animated:NO];
    [self.anotherSlider setValue:0.5f animated:NO];
}

- (IBAction)setOneSlider:(UISlider *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Setting aSlider to %f", sender.value);
    self.sl1Val = sender.value;
    [self doAThing];
}

- (IBAction)setTwoSlider:(UISlider *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Setting anotherSlider to %f", sender.value);
    self.sl2Val = sender.value;
    [self doBThing];
}
@end
```

The calls to `setOneSlider` and `setTwoSlider` are wired to the value changed events of the two sliders.  That works perfectly well.  Unfortunately, I have not connected the sliders to their programmatic handles, because the call to `resetSliders` yields no change in the UI, even with a call added to `setNeedsDisplay` on the two slider elements.

When `resetSliders` is called, the log shows:

```
2015-04-28 12:22:19.608 myApp[4489:681127] Resetting sliders sl1: (null) sl2: (null)
```

Can anyone indicate to me how to set the `self.aSlider` and `self.anotherSlider` with the correct object handles?

To add some color:  I have dragged the UI representation of the sliders to their respective @property declarations, and I can see that they have filled-in grey circles in the margin, indicating that they've been wired.  The Connections Inspector shows both a "Value Changed" event trigger and a Referencing Outlet connecting myApp to the slider(s).

I'm extremely new to IOS programming and am reaching the limits of learning-by-failing.

Comment: I have gone through the triage/debug listed by @jszumski and @ picciano below (though they seemingly take polar opposite tacks), but my end result is the same.  Calling my reset method prints (null) for the two sliders, when I am expecting the slider object, or at least the address of the slider object.  I don't even care which, just proof of life.  Additionally the reset functionality is failing when calling the setValue method, due to there being no reference to the slider.

Comment: Can you post updated code in the question?

Comment: Updated with current broken code.  Removed the @synthesize(s) and ivars, and changed all references to the sliders to 'self.'  I also re-connected the UI elements in Interface Builder just to make sure I had the correct connections.

Comment: you need two `@end`s: one to end the first `@interface` block and one to end the `@implementation` block.

Comment: Sorry, those are present, just not in my code snippet.  I'm in a fairly large and quite proprietary app so I'm hand-coding some obfuscated representations of my actual mostly-working code.

Comment: Maybe I'm asking the wrong thing.  If I had first created my slider(s), and associated the proper event code for valueChanged, and that was working fine, what steps would I take to then make the same slider(s) programmatically available to my app?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you still need to connect these outlets in Interface Builder:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *aSlider;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *anotherSlider;
```

---

Also you don't need to declare properties and ivars for the same sliders.  Just declare and use the properties you already have.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

and

```
-(void)resetSliders  
{
    // note the addition of 'self.' below
    NSLog(@"Resetting sliders sl1: %@ sl2: %@", self.aSlider, self.anotherSlider);
    [self.aSlider       setTo:0.5f animated:NO];
    [self.anotherSlider setTo:0.5f animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Can you describe that process to me precisely?  I have dragged the UI representation of the sliders to their respective @property declarations, and I can see that they have filled-in grey circles in the margin, indicating that they've been wired.

I'm extremely new to IOS programming and am reaching the limits of learning-by-failing.

Comment: That sounds like they are connected.  I think your issue is addressed in the second half of my answer... you are using the shadowed ivars (which are uninitialized) instead of the connected properties.

Comment: I removed the ivars that seemingly masked the slider handles, but now upon using them directly in resetSliders, I see build errors:

`No visible @interface for 'UISlider' declares the selector 'setTo:animated:'`

Comment: Use [`setValue:animated: `](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISlider/setValue:animated:) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The properties should be defined inside the `@interface` blocks. Yours are currently outside. Additionally, they should probably be `weak` instead of `retain`, and no need for the `@synthesize` statements or the ivars.

Lastly, when you reference them in code, you should do so as `self.aSlider`, not just `aSlider`.

Comment: So I have, as above, completely removed all instance representations of the sliders.  The event-driven functionality still works fine, but I cannot programmatically set the value of my sliders to perform the reset.  Thoughts?

Comment: At this point, your code looks correct. I would suggest removing the @property lines and add them back by dragging the UISlider from InterfaceBuilder into your code...again.

Comment: Guh.  Do you know of any instrumentation I could add to attempt to assign the slider objects properly?  I attempted something like `if (aSlider == nil) aSlider = sender;` in the setSlider code, but that somehow triggered an infinite loop of calls into that function.  I imagine I failed to clear a secret flag  that indicated that the event had finished, or something similar.